# Top Down Recursive Parsing (simple examples)

Tags: parsing

In theoretical terms - not looking for specific implementation details, but how do I write a top-down recursive parser for a simple grammar example such as this:

```
 HAZ ::= FOO | BAR
 FOO ::= “tea” BAR | POT
 BAR ::= POT
 POT ::= “abc” FOO “tea"
```

Comment: Is this homework? Do you have any thoughts on how you might do this?

Comment: Not homework, just study material. I have a general idea of recursive descent parsing however with this particular grammar I was unsure how to handle the ambiguity between FOO and BAR and in particular the recursive loop between POT and FOO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer for a general method for coding top down recursive descent parsers directly from a grammar:

[Is there an alternative for flex/bison that is usable on 8-bit embedded systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769)